# SQLite FTS5 Table search inconsistency

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search

I have a TRANSACTIONS Table which was created with the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE TRANSACTIONS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, DESC VARCHAR(255), COMMENT VARCHAR(1024), INVOICE VARCHAR(255));
```

Then I created the FTS5 virtual table with the query:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE TRANSACTIONS_FTS USING FTS5(
    content="TRANSACTIONS",
    content_rowid="ID",
    DESC,
    COMMENT,
    INVOICE,
);
```

Then I filled TRANSACTIONS_FTS using the following query:

```
INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS_FTS (rowid, DESC, COMMENT, INVOICE) SELECT ID, DESC, COMMENT, INVOICE FROM TRANSACTIONS;
```

And now I am running the 2 search queries. The 1st one:

```
SELECT * FROM TRANSACTIONS_FTS WHERE TRANSACTIONS_FTS MATCH 'cabana';
```

which gives me 27 results.

While the second one

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.*
FROM TRANSACTIONS AS T
JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM TRANSACTIONS_FTS
    WHERE TRANSACTIONS_FTS MATCH 'cabana'
) AS T_MATCH ON T.ID = T_MATCH.rowid;
```

gives 0 results. Why is it not giving the same results? How can I debug the Join?

Comment: As you use external table the fst table need to be filled by a trigger on the TRANSACTION table. Search for « Create a table. And an external content fts5 table to index it» in [sqlite documentation page](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html)

Comment: Yes, I created the triggers but for now I populated the existing data in the TRANSACTIONS table using the INSERT statement. And there have been no new transactions. All I testing is results in the existing data.

Comment: Can you show the trigger ? In your example you enter data in FTS but no data in TRANSACTION. In the page I gave you there is an explanation on the inconsistency that can occurs between fts and content table.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to make it work. Seems like rowid in the FTS table is not returned unles syou specify it directly. So the search query that works is:

```
SELECT T.*
        FROM TRANSACTIONS AS T
        JOIN (
            SELECT rowid
            FROM TRANSACTIONS_FTS
            WHERE TRANSACTIONS_FTS MATCH 'Cabana' -- Add more words as needed
        ) AS T_MATCH ON T.ID = T_MATCH.rowid
```